# How can I place a line/arrow on an enlarged node's edge?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I'd like to connect the nodes by their edges, meaning getting the arrow on abc's end to touch the rectangle's left margin. It worked flawlessly with `wordsa` but I haven't been successful in finding the right method for `abc`.

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[
11pt
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{
tikz,
relsize,
tgheros
}

\usetikzlibrary{
    calc,trees,shadows,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,
    decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,
    matrix,shapes.symbols,patterns,intersections%,fit
    }

\pgfdeclarelayer{background layer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground layer}
\pgfsetlayers{background layer,main,foreground layer}

\tikzset{
    rolle/.style=
    {
        rectangle,
        drop shadow={opacity=0.5},
        minimum width=4em,
        minimum height=4em,
        text width=4cm,
        draw=black!80,
        very thick,
        fill=black!40,
        font=\sffamily\bfseries,
        align=center
    },
    einheit/.style=
    {
        rectangle,
        rounded corners, 
        minimum height=2em,
        minimum width=4em,
    draw=black!80,
        fill=black!20,
    font=\sffamily
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\small,node distance=0.5cm]
    \matrix (m) [
        matrix of nodes,
        nodes in empty cells,
        row sep=7mm,
        column sep=3mm,
        inner sep=7pt
    ] {
    %
    \node[rolle] {123}; & \node[rolle] {456}; & \node[rolle] {789}; \\
    %
    \node[einheit] {words}; & & \node[minimum width=3cm] (abc) {}; \\
    %
    & \node[einheit] (wordsa) {wordsa}; & \\
%
    & \node[einheit] (wordsb) {wordsb}; & \\
    %
    & \node[einheit] {companies}; & \\
%
    \node[einheit] {thing}; & & \node[minimum width=3cm] (xyz) {};\\
    };
    %
    \draw[thick] (current bounding box.north west) rectangle (current bounding box.south east);
    \draw[thick,fill=black!20] (current bounding box.north west) rectangle ([yshift=1cm]current bounding box.north east) node[midway] {Something Important};
    %
    \draw[einheit] (abc.north east) rectangle (xyz.south west) node[midway] (new) {abc};
    %
    \draw[thick,dashed,<->] (new.west) -- (wordsa.east);
    %
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added `,minimum width=3cm` to `node[midway]` in the line

```
\draw[einheit] (abc.north east) rectangle (xyz.south west) node[midway] (new) {abc};
```

For some cosmetic changes, consider adding `shorten <=2pt,shorten >=2pt` to

```
\draw[thick,dashed,<->] (new.west) -- (wordsa.east);
```

=>

```
\documentclass[
11pt
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{
tikz,
relsize,
tgheros
}

\usetikzlibrary{
    calc,trees,shadows,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,
    decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,
    matrix,shapes.symbols,patterns,intersections%,fit
    }

\pgfdeclarelayer{background layer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground layer}
\pgfsetlayers{background layer,main,foreground layer}

\tikzset{
    rolle/.style=
    {
        rectangle,
        drop shadow={opacity=0.5},
        minimum width=4em,
        minimum height=4em,
        text width=4cm,
        draw=black!80,
        very thick,
        fill=black!40,
        font=\sffamily\bfseries,
        align=center
    },
    einheit/.style=
    {
        rectangle,
        rounded corners, 
        minimum height=2em,
        minimum width=4em,
    draw=black!80,
        fill=black!20,
    font=\sffamily
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\small,node distance=0.5cm]
    \matrix (m) [
        matrix of nodes,
        nodes in empty cells,
        row sep=7mm,
        column sep=3mm,
        inner sep=7pt
    ] {
    %
    \node[rolle] {123}; & \node[rolle] {456}; & \node[rolle] {789}; \\
    %
    \node[einheit] {words}; & & \node[minimum width=3cm] (abc) {}; \\
    %
    & \node[einheit] (wordsa) {wordsa}; & \\
    %
    & \node[einheit] (wordsb) {wordsb}; & \\
    %
    & \node[einheit] {companies}; & \\
    %
    \node[einheit] {thing}; & & \node[minimum width=3cm] (xyz) {};\\
    };
    %
    \draw[thick] (current bounding box.north west) rectangle (current bounding box.south east);
    \draw[thick,fill=black!20] (current bounding box.north west) rectangle ([yshift=1cm]current bounding box.north east) node[midway] {Something Important};
    %
    \draw[einheit] (abc.north east) rectangle (xyz.south west) node[midway,minimum width=3cm] (new) {abc};
    %
    \draw[thick,dashed,<->,shorten >=2pt,shorten <=2pt] (new.west) -- (wordsa.east);
    %
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would you like to make the answer into a complete example?

Comment: I honestly can't figure out if that is a hint masked as a question or an honest inquiry. But no, I am going to do it.

Comment: I'd rather use something like     `\draw[thick,dashed,<->] (abc.north west|-new.west) -- (wordsa.east);` so you don't have to manually specify the width.